# multiple jquery scripts or merge to single?

Tags: jquery

Can I have my scripts like this? or can I make into one for all 3 images, the about and news images work like this but the gallery one doesn't animate at all?? also is it ok to have the jquery src script once like this?thanks

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script>
 $(function() {
 var height  = '430';
 var left   = '150'
 $("#about").animate({
 opacity: 1,
 top: height,
 left: left
 }, 5000, function () {
 // Animation complete.
 });
 });
 </script>    
 <script>
 $(function() {
 var height  = '375';
 var left   = '250'
 $("#news").animate({
 opacity: 1,
 top: height,
 left: left
 }, 6000, function () {
 // Animation complete.
 });
 });
 </script>
 <script>
 $(function() {
 var height  = '325';
 var left   = '250'
 $("#gallery").animate({
 opacity: 1,
 top: height,
 left: left
 }, 7000, function () {
 // Animation complete.
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: you may need to provide the html code for us to see why the `#gallery` is not working, or even better, a JSFIDDLE.

Comment: My fault for got to update the id on gallery in the html, when you said that I looked there right away thanks.

Comment: Is the code ok as is above or should it be merged into one single?

Comment: I would merge: create three arrays with the height/left/duration values and then assign a class so that `$(".AnimatedClass").animate(...`

Comment: Ok but I want them to be positioned differently hence the id's. Is there a way to tell the second not to start until the first has finished and the third not to start until the second has finished? ta